# Recursive function for going through digits not progressing

Tags: prolog

I am trying to do a predicate called "all_even", with one parameter. It will take that parameter and check if it's even or odd using mod(); if it is odd then the predicate should stop working, which I persume will be done by the cut (!) feature.

But it seems like my recursive case seems to not be working. When I traced it, the number I inputted, 2968, doesn't change, but is eventually overwritten by some weird number that breaks the whole thing.

For context, here is my current code:

```
all_even(X) :- mod(X,2)\==0.%base case
    
all_even(X) :- mod(X,2)=:=0,
    all_even(X1), X1 is X // 10. %recursive case
```

and here's the tracing feedback

```
Call:all_even(2968)
 Call:2968 mod 2\==0
 Exit:2968 mod 2\==0
 Exit:all_even(2968)

1true

 Redo:all_even(2968)
 Call:2968 mod 2=:=0
 Exit:2968 mod 2=:=0
 Call:all_even(_5638)
 Call:_5638 mod 2\==0
 Exit:_5638 mod 2\==0
 Exit:all_even(_5638)
 Call:_5638 is 2968//10
 Exit:296 is 2968//10
 Exit:all_even(2968)

2true

 Redo:all_even(_5638)
 Call:_5638 mod 2=:=0
 Exception:_5638 mod 2=:=0
Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are a couple of problems with your code:

- the first clause (your base case) succeeds when the number is not even
- the recursive clause calls `all_even(X1)` without first computing `X1`, so later when doing arithmetic operations it will give you the exception that the argument is not sufficiently instantiated.

So you should first compute `X1` and then do the recursive call:

```
all_even(X) :-
  X \= 0,
  mod(X,2)=:=0,
  X1 is X // 10,
  all_even(X1) . %recursive case
all_even(0). %base case
```

This procedure does not work as a generator because it cannot cope with unbound variables. For that you may use clp(FD):

```
all_even(0). %base case
all_even(X) :-
  X #\= 0,
  0 #= X mod 2,
  X1 #= X // 10,
  all_even(X1) . %recursive case
```

sample run:

```
?- all_even(X), label([X]).
X = 0 ;
X = -8 ;
X = -6 ;
X = -4 ;
X = -2 ;
X = 2 ;
X = 4 ;
X = 6 ;
X = 8 ;
X = -88 ;
X = -86 
...
```

Comment: i forgot to specify, but all_even should return false if theres a single odd digit in that number. 

Specifying X1 solved one of the issues, and I changed my base case to one completely different to one that would actually stop the recursion (checking if X =< 0). Now my predicate works! Thank you for the answer!